# PhpStorm speed up project creation when working with existing files on a remote server

Tags: phpstorm

When creating a new project from existing files on a remote server (via SFTP), it takes a long time to get all the files (three hours for a Magento 2 installation). If I were to compress and transfer the installation, it would take less than ten minutes to transfer.

Is there a way I can manually transfer the files (outside of PhpStorm) onto my dev machine, then have PhpStorm index the local copy of the files for its code intelligence, but tell it about the link to the remote server, for deployment and debugging?

Comment: Yes. Just use "Open" and point to the local folder -- PhpStorm will create a project out of those files. After indexing is finished you just setup Deployment entry and whatever else you need manually.

Comment: @LazyOne I've tried that and everything works as expected apart from debugging.

Comment: This mean -- you need to better (properly) configure it -- maybe you have missed or misunderstood some needed steps. Have a read this if you have not done it yet: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the help. Turns out you have to manually set the path mappings under Language & Frameworks>PHP>Servers. If you create a project from remote files the dialogues prompt you for the same information and are able to create the correct PHP>Servers mappings automatically. Seems a bit of an oversight that this doesn't work when adding a deployment server.

Comment: 1) There is no guarantee that Deployment paths will be suitable here (simple reason: symbolic link -- xdebug work with final/resolved paths) 2) There is an option somewhere there in debug settings (I believe) that allows to pick up mappings from Deployment (to lazy to double check the name and location)